# How to make elements to stay under a sticky element css?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a contianer that contains some header and items.
I want the header to be sticky and the items always be under him.
The problem is the items always overlap the sticky element.
I have demo code

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: yellow
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 50px;
}

.item {
  margin-top: 20px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sticky">
    sticky el
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    fdsfdsf
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    fdsfdsf
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    fdsfdsf
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    fdsfdsf
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    fdsfdsf
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    fdsfdsf
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    fdsfdsf
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    fdsfdsf
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    fdsfdsf
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    fdsfdsf
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sticky element doesn't have a background, so the items underneath it are still visible. If it has a background it will cover them.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: yellow
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background: #c00;
}

.item {
  margin-top: 20px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sticky">
    sticky el
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    fdsfdsf
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    fdsfdsf
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    fdsfdsf
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    fdsfdsf
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    fdsfdsf
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    fdsfdsf
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    fdsfdsf
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    fdsfdsf
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    fdsfdsf
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    fdsfdsf
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  background: #ccc
}

.sticky {
  top: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background: #876;
  position: sticky;
}

.item {
  padding-top: 30px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sticky">
    sticky Header
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    information
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    information
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    information
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    information
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    information
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    information
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    information
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    information
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    information
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    information
  </div>
</div>
```